# How to add custom angular 4 components in a bootbox dialog?

Tags: angular, bootbox

I am trying to display some user information in a bootbox dialog. There is a custom component that  I need to display within the dialog.

```
var dialog = bootbox.dialog({
   title: 'User Information Table',
   message: `<div class="myclass"><app-charts></app-charts></div>`,
   buttons: {
  cancel: {
    label: "Cancel!",
    className: 'btn-danger',
      callback: function(){

  }
})
```

The  template is not compiled and hence is being displayed as a normal tag in the bootbox. 
Is there a way to display an angular 4 component inside the bootbox dialog?

Comment: where do you use this code? do have you access to DOM elements?

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com I think yes. He has access to DOM elements http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html#also-applies-to-alert-confirm-prompt%0A%0Acustom-dialog-using-init

Comment: This code is part of a different component to display a table of users. I do have access to DOM elements. Yes.

Comment: you can then take advantage of dynamic components, you can pass a DOM element to `create` method

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Bootbox will not do this. I use `MatDialog` for creating dialogs with custom components. Check it out:

https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview